# Field Integrity Exception on LinkedEntityID

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am running into a field integrity exception when trying to change the share type of ContentDocumentLink in After insert [This is the screenshot of the error I am running into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlXVd.png). Here is a snippet of my code my code. Please Help.

```
for(ContentDocumentLink cV2ValidateTitle: Trigger.new){
        for(ContentVersion cvData : titlefromCV){
            for(String rName: mapOfRoleNameUser.keySet()){
                for(ContentDocumentLink CDLProjMilid : allReqRecords){
                    if(CDLProjMilid.ContentDocumentId == cV2ValidateTitle.ContentDocumentId){
                if(cvData.Title.contains(rName)){
                    ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                    cdl.ContentDocumentId = cV2ValidateTitle.ContentDocumentId;
                    cdl.LinkedEntityId =  cV2ValidateTitle.LinkedEntityId;
                    cdl.ShareType = 'V';
                    system.debug('cdl: '+cdl);
                    listOfCDL.add(cdl);
                }
            }
                }
            }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sharing all of your code for that trigger. which makes it hard as some of the code relies on the previous lines of code. Your code is also not well indented for readability.

I am assuming for the code provided and the screenshot that you're simply creating another ContentDocumentLink with the exact same LinkedEntityId and ContentDocumentId, try removing that code. As the error suggests you can't do that.